# Statsvn doesn't generate HTML for all the commits in the log file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, statsvn

I am using Tortoise SVN to checkout a project with several releases -dates- to my machine, and then i generated a the log file for the entire project, then i use StatSVN to generate the HTML files for the commits. The SVN log files has commits that are more 10 years old-which i need-, but the HTML files generated by the Statsvn has only commits for 5 years, i am missing out most of the commits because of this, any idea hot to fix this ?

Comment: I am hit by the same problem, did you find out why it happens?

Comment: not really ! i gave up on the issue and had to ignore those projects !